# Is there a problem using a "shared" private property in a class to build fluent/evolving DB query?

Tags: php, design-patterns, solid-principles

I'm trying to write a class that relies on some legacy code to fetch data from database related to a particular table (*productcode*)

For not repeating myself, I implement a private property $sql that holds the "evolving" query and finally applying getResult() on it (as this snippet shows it)

My question: is there any design principle violation by implementing this pattern? (specially adopting the "shared" $sql property). If the answer is yes, why and what is the proper way to do it?

```
<?php

class ProductCodeDataSource
{
    use dbmanager_aware_trait;
    private $sql;

    public function findByProductId($productId)
    {
        $this->sql = [];
        $this->sql['fields'] = 'productcode_value';
        $this->sql['tables'] = 'productcode';
        $this->sql['where'][] = sprintf('productcode_product_id = %d', (int) $productId);
        $this->sql['order'][] = 'productcode_default';

        return $this;
    }

    public function findOneByProductId($productId)
    {
        $this->findByProductId($productId);
        $this->sql['limit'] = 1;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getResult()
    {
        // get_all_value is a legacy method that fetches data from mysql DB

        // build_select_ext is also a legacy method that builds sql queries from
        // $sql array structures

        return$this->dbmanager->get_all_value($db->build_select_ext($this->sql));
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you share the `$sql` property? How does the method `build_select_ext` look like? How much do you trust your inputs? Should you parameterize them?

Comment: SO is not the most suitable place for asking code review question. There is a dedicated SE page: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: as you see in the code  "private $sql;" so it is just a private property and each findXXX method works on it to change it to a certain point, the build_select_ext is just turning this $sql array variable into a $sql string , inputs are perfectly trustworthy, and there is no need to parametize them

Comment: So you mean that you are reusing the object? How could this impact anything if you clear the `$sql` array each time you call `findByProductId`? Building dynamic SQL statements is a common thing. Take a look at [EasyDB class by Paragonie](https://github.com/paragonie/easydb/blob/master/src/EasyStatement.php)